# CSS: clean solution to the margin collapse issue when floating an element

Tags: css, layout, css-float, margin

Example HTML+CSS:

```
<html>
  <body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
    <div style="float: right;">first</div>
    <div style="margin-top: 2em;">second</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Desired behavior:** the `first` div floats to the top-right of the window.  **Actual behavior:** it floats 2em below the desired position.  **Reason:** [margin collapsing](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing).

Despite identifying the problem, the solutions I can come up with feel like hacks:

- change `body` style to  `margin: -1px 0 0 0; border-top: 1px solid;`.
- insert `<div style="height: 1px; margin-bottom: -1px;"></div>` before `first`
- insert the above `<div>` between the `first` and `second`

**Is there a clean, idiomatic way of avoiding this issue?**

Comment: Related: [clear and collapse fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007322/clear-fix-and-uncollapse-margins-with-css-without-side-effects).

Answer (score 22):

Adding `overflow: hidden;` to the `body` should solve your problem. It defines a new block formatting context as described in this article: [The magic of overflow: hidden](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/).

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sxqxw/) (the `body` tag is automatically added by jsFiddle, that's why I haven't included it in the HTML markup)

**UPDATE** (thx to @clairesuzy): This solution does not work if `body` has `padding: 0`. Until I can find a better way, I can only suggest to add a wrapper around the two divs (at least I deserve now @Marcel's downwote :)), which I still think is cleaner than the solutions posted by the OP. I normally add a wrapper around floated stuff anyways (makes it easier to handle older browsers most of the time), most of the time it does not need to be added deliberately, because it is logically and semantically required.

So for now, I can come up with this:

```
<body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
   <div id="container" style="overflow: hidden;">
       <div style="float: right;">first</div>
       <div style="margin-top: 2em;">second</div>
   </div>
</body>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sxqxw/1/)

**UPDATE 2**: After thinking it through, and reading comments, I really think that `overflow: hidden` (or anything other than `overflow: visible`) on the container is the right solution. The only exception where it did not work for me is setting it on the `body` element, which is a very rare situation anyways. In these rare situations, you can try using `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;` instead of floating.

Another possible workaround: I have also found that setting `display: inline-block; width: 100%;` on `body` works indeed.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sxqxw/2/)

Comment: Sorry, doesn't seem like a 'clean' solution to me. It works but it isn't very practical, unless an extra element is introduced.

Comment: @Marcel I'd understand your concern about introducing a new element, but I haven't done so. Have you checked the Fiddle? I'd be happy to make it better if you have problems with it. I like learning from criticism, so please share your thoughts.

Comment: @bazmegakapa I really thought this was the answer, but it doesn't work, the actual fiddle does, but only because the jsfiddle result-light.css is adding some body padding (10px) -  and padding as we know is a 'cure' for collapsing margins.. 1px is enough for it to work like @eegg's border-top solution, seems it does need a extra wrapper element to apply the overflow fix to.

Comment: @clairesuzy Thanks for this clarification. Now I feel I don't understand something about CSS :). I will investigate this thing farther and update when I have something, or learn something new when someone posts a good answer.

Comment: @bazmegakapa yours is the good answer, only not applied to the `body` element which is highly unlikely in a real world scenario anyway.. overflow hidden on the parent element i.e add a container div (except body, which is the root formatting context) will work. It's highly unlikely that you would want to be floating the very first element in source and not want to have it have a container div of some sort ;)

Comment: Switched my vote. Setting `overflow:hidden` on a "wrap" element is not only a good solution to this problem but is probably already in common use for clearing floats.

Comment: @Marcel Thanks. `overflow: hidden`'s *magic* is quite useful in several situations.

Comment: @bažmegakapa display: inline-block; width: 100%; on body worked for me. Why does inline-block work? I don't understand the reasoning.

Comment: @Anthony That's a good question, I would look into it, but don't have time right now. Hm, thinking that we are already on a Q&A site, maybe you could ask a question about this. Please also post the link to your question here because I'm also interested in the answer :).

Comment: I'd prefer `overflow: auto` over `overflow: hidden` as you might have some effect inside the div that should go outside (maybe relative positioned elements or pseude elements, maybe some box-shadow). In fact any other value than `visible` should work. Both of course only work properly, if the width and height are not fixed and less then the content's.

Answer (score 3):

### SOLUTION

add `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: scroll;` to both `html` and `body` tag.

### IF YOU WANT TO KNOW WHY

Creating block formatting context(BFC) on `body` tag.

#### Why it does not work if I add `overflow: hidden;` only to `body`?

Here is why:

[W3C#block-formatting](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting)

> Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers (such as inline-blocks, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (***except when that value has been propagated to the viewport***) establish new block formatting contexts for their contents.

[W3C#overflow](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visufx.html#overflow):

> UAs must apply the 'overflow' property set on the root element to the viewport.
>
> When the root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML "html" element, and that element has an HTML "BODY" element or an XHTML "body" element as a child, user agents must instead apply the 'overflow' property from ***the first such child element* to the viewport, if the value on the root element is 'visible'**.
>
> The 'visible' value when used for the viewport must be interpreted as 'auto'.
>
> ***The element from which the value is propagated* must have a used value for 'overflow' of 'visible'**.

`the first such child element` and `The element from which the value is propagated` refer to `body` tag in this case.

In other words, if you add `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: scroll;` to `body` while the value of `html`'s `overflow` property is `visible`, the value of `body`'s `overflow` property(`hidden` or `auto` or `scroll`) will be propagated to the viewport. So according to the first W3C quote, `body` would not establish new block formatting context.

However, if you add `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: scroll;` to `html`, the `overflow` value of 'body' would not be propagated and hence establish new block formatting context.

Comment: None of the answers except this one explains why overflow on body doesn't establish new block formatting context, which I think the key to the issue.

Answer (score 2):

On the parent `div` add this `#parent {padding 1px 0; }`  this was a huge issue for me and it took me for ever to find a solution. I saw on a post like 2 years and this fixes the collapse.

Answer (score 1):

Add `float: left;` to the second div.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5ggw/)

Comment: While it solves the problem, it might not be desirable on most occasions.

Answer (score 1):

The W3C specs describes this about collapsing margins:

> "In this specification, the expression collapsing margins means that adjoining margins (no non-empty content, padding, or border areas, or clearance separate them) of two or more boxes (which may be next to one another or nested) combine to form a single margin."

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

best way to deal with collapsing margins is to just add one pixel to the top or bottom padding of the element that has the collapsed margin.

if the margin was collapsing on top.. then:

```
#element-with-collapsed-margin {
   padding-top:1px;
}
```

or **border-top** would fix this as well

```
#element-with-collapsed-margin {
   border-top:1px solid transparent;
}
```

if your bottom margin is collapsed then you would add **padding-bottom:1px;** or **border-top:1px solid transparent;**

basically any border or padding on top or bottom will stop the margins from collapsing when you have they above one another or even when you have elements nested inside each other that have margin collapse

good reference:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

..

Answer (score 1):

Another trick that you can use when `overflow:hidden` is not suitable:

```
.clr:before, .clr:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

This snippet has the side-effect of containing all floats as well.

Comment: font-size:0 and a space inside content is not required for modern browsers. Tested as on IE10, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: .clr:before,.clr:after{display:table;content:"";clear:both} works in Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+, Chrome, Opera 9+, IE 8+, according to http://nicolasgallagher.com/better-float-containment-in-ie/

Answer (score 0):

It might be strange but in new versions of Chrome and Mozilla you can achieve the desired behavior (first div is at the top right) by adding wrapper div with border

```
<html>
  <body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
    <div style="border: 1px solid black">
        <div style="float: right;">first</div>
        <div style="margin-top: 2em;">second</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `clear: right` to second second

```
<html>
  <body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
    <div style="float: right;">first</div>
    <div style="clear: right">second</div>
  </body>
</html>
```