# Why do I need a border for these divs to render correctly?

Tags: html, css

I have a block of code that looks like this:

```
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="right-gradient">
    <div class="left-gradient">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>

.right-gradient
{
    background: url('Images/RightGradient.png') repeat-y right top transparent;
}
.left-gradient
{
    background: url('Images/RightGradient.png') repeat-y left top transparent;
}
```

It should result in something like this:

```
|-------------------|
|##### Header ######|
|-------------------|
|//               \\|
|//    Content    \\|
|//               \\|
|//               \\|
---------------------
```

However it instead renders like this:

```
|-------------------|
|##### Header ######|
|-------------------|
|                   |  - Note the extra space here
|//               \\|
|//    Content    \\|
|//               \\|
|//               \\|
---------------------
```

While trying to figure out where the extra space between the header and the content is coming from, I have discovered that adding a border to my divs actually corrects the problem and removes the offending space between the header and the content.

```
.right-gradient
{
    background: url('Images/RightGradient.png') repeat-y right top transparent;
    border: 1px red solid;
}
.left-gradient
{
    background: url('Images/RightGradient.png') repeat-y left top transparent;
    border: 1px blue solid;
}
```

Why is this?

[jsfiddle with sample code reproducing the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/2XReh/)

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle with the code.

Comment: do you have any margins on your divs?

Comment: Sounds like a margin collapse.  The first element inside your content block has a top margin.  Adding a border to the content block prevents the margin from collapsing.

Comment: @ZoltanToth Yes, however I have removed the extra divs around the @RenderBody() and still noticing the same problem in multiple browsers. I'm working on putting together a jsfiddle with the code now.

Comment: @cimmanon You are correct, I do have a `margin-top` in my content and I can reproduce the problem in jsfiddle with that. Thank you, you should consider posting that as an answer explaining why the problem occurs :)

Comment: @ChrisHerbert jsfiddle link has been added to the bottom of the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, your margins have collapsed.  MDN has a explanation of the phenomenon:

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block with the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block with the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin_collapsing

Answer (score 1):

This problem is pretty well documented if you google it, not sure if its a bug or exactly why it happens though.

Try `overflow:hidden;` to get rid of the space without having to add a border.

Comment: Using `overflow:hidden;` does indeed work, although I am very curious why I need to do this in the first place. I suspect [cimmanon's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223638/why-do-i-need-a-border-for-these-divs-to-render-correctly/14223722#comment19729813_14223638) is what results in my problem :)

Comment: Yup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204670/css-clean-solution-to-the-margin-collapse-issue-when-floating-an-element