# CSS spacing issue in windows 8 horizontal design

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with one of my designs.
I have created a design which is much like the windows 8 tiles, but there is an issue that arises sometimes.

The **.row** and **.large-*** sometimes have some mysterious gaps between the top of their containing elements.
There is no padding or margins anywhere that should be causing it, but it is happening.

I have made a fiddler example to show it in effect.
Please can someone have a look at it and tell me what I am doing wrong:

http://jsfiddle.net/34pk327u/

this is the HTML before it is rendered:

```
<div class="row">
    <a class="back" href="/"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></a>

    <section class="large-4 columns">
        <h1 class="column-title">Orders <small>quick search</small></h1>

        <form name="orderFrom" role="form" ng-submit="customerServices.orderSearch()">
            <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="small-10 columns typeahead-icon">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="customerServices.searchTerm" placeholder="Search" typeahead="item for items in customerServices.autoComplete() | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-loading="customerServices.loading" typeahead-min-length="2">
                    <i ng-show="customerServices.loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="small-2 columns">
                    <button type="submit" class="button postfix">Go</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>

    <section class="tile-column large-8 columns" tile-column>
        <h1 class="column-title">Recent orders</h1>

        <div class="loading" ajax-loader ng-show="customerServices.recent.loading"></div>

        <div class="alert alert-box" ng-show="!customerServices.recent.loading && customerServices.recent.data.length === 0">
            No records have been found that match your search.
            <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
        </div>

        <a class="tile large" ng-href="/customer-services/view-order/{{order.orderNumber}}" tile ng-repeat="order in customerServices.recent.data" id="{{order.orderNumber}}">
            <div class="text">
                <strong ng-bind="order.account.accountNumber"></strong> <span ng-bind="order.account.name"></span><br />
                <span ng-bind="order.raisedBy"></span><br />
                <span ng-bind="order.orderNumber"></span><br />
                <span ng-bind="order.getDescription()"></span><br />
            </div>
        </a>
    </section>

    <section class="tile-column large-8 columns" tile-column>
        <h1 class="column-title">Sync failures</h1>

        <div class="loading" ajax-loader ng-show="customerServices.failures.loading"></div>

        <div class="alert alert-box" ng-show="!customerServices.failures.loading && customerServices.failures.data.length === 0">
            No records have been found that match your search.
            <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
        </div>

        <a class="tile large" ng-href="/customer-services/view-order/{{order.orderNumber}}" tile ng-repeat="order in customerServices.failures.data" id="{{order.orderNumber}}">
            <div class="text">
                <strong ng-bind="order.account.accountNumber"></strong> <span ng-bind="order.account.name"></span><br />
                <span ng-bind="order.raisedBy"></span><br />
                <span ng-bind="order.orderNumber"></span><br />
                <span ng-bind="order.getDescription()"></span><br />
            </div>
        </a>
    </section>
</div>
```

**Update 1**

I have updated the fiddle and added some borders so you can see the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/34pk327u/2/

if you look at the quick search, it looks like it's 40px (ish) below the top of the row, but the other columns are in the right place.

Comment: I'm unclear as to which elements you're referring to. Do you mean the blue tiles, like Brookside Cpts?

Comment: What "some mysterious gaps" might you possibly be talking about? Maybe show a picture of something so that we can understand the question?

Comment: See this question - I think it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204670/css-clean-solution-to-the-margin-collapse-issue-when-floating-an-element

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what "mysterious gaps" you're referring to, but you can try adding `padding: 0;` to **.row** and **.large-***