# <header> tag's elements aren't starting from the top

Tags: css, html

In the following code the header tag's content isn't starting from the top of the screen,

```css
body {
       margin: 0px; border: 2px solid green; 

}
header {
        
       width: 100%;
         height: 25vh;
         background-color: gray;
         
         text-align: center;
         margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
         
      }
```

```html
<header>
<h1 class="heading"> Syco Scientist Records </h1>

</header>
```

Why is this happening? Now if I set a border to header tag then the contents start from the top without leaving any space.

Comment: All browsers will apply default CSS to common html elements, you need to reset them. Save yourself some troubles next time, i suggest you use [Eric Meyer's CSS Reset code](http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/). Add this at the top of your CSS file.

Comment: @IndieRok thanks for the link.

Comment: @LGSon I'll accept your answer once I fully understand the overflow and margin-collapsing concept.

Comment: I updated my answer, together with some more links, with an effort to explain as simple as possible. Hopefully that will help, and if not, I'm okay with not getting my answer accepted.

Comment: @LGSon Your answer is ok. the problem is that I am yet learning html css. I started from w3school and soon realized I was doing wrong so now I've found the official tutorial of w3.org https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the margin on `h1`, or add `padding-top: 1px;` to the `header` or, as in my sample, add `overflow: auto` to the `header` (it can actually be anything but `overflow: visible`).

The reason why this happens is because of [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing), which in a simple way means that when 2 element's margin meets, one takes out the other.

If the margin is set to the first element, direct after the body or within a parent direct following the body, it pushes all elements down by that margin and to solve that a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) is needed to clear that, so it works pretty much the same way as with floating, where a clear float is needed.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25vh;
  background-color: gray;

  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="heading"> Syco Scientist Records </h1>
</header>
```

More to read about collapsing margins

- [CSS: clean solution to the margin collapse issue when floating an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204670/css-clean-solution-to-the-margin-collapse-issue-when-floating-an-element)
- http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing
- http://blog.csdn.net/xiongzhengxiang/article/details/7486118
- https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: tags like <h1>, <h2>, .. , <p> have an initial margin value

Comment: Do the tags have margin with respect to the body? And if I set border to the `<header>` tag then why does the margin of `<h1>` vanishes?

Comment: Also when I set margin 0 for h1 then I am not able to centre the heading vertically.

Comment: @user31782 Updated my answer with yet another way

Comment: How does the `overflow: auto` remove the margin-collapsing effect?

Comment: @user31782 It clears the collapsing effect, read more here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins