# How can I prevent a floated div from inheriting his sibling's margin-top?

Tags: css, css-float

I have some html code that look like this sample here :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="A" style="float:right; Background-color: Red;">Alpha</div>
    <div id="B" style="margin-top: 20px; Background-color: Green;">Bravo</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I'd like to achieve is have the A div in the upper right corner and the B div aligned on the left 20 pixels from the top of the page. As you can see below, it does exactly what I want in IE8, but it doesn't quite works in Chrome and Firefox.

[image]

Because it's often the case, I suppose Chrome and FF are right to render it this way and IE8 is not following the standard. So my question is how can I get the desired result (What IE does in the SS) across all browser?

EDIT1&2: I edited the screenshot to show that I really want the Bravo div to be on the left of the Alpha div *but 20px lower* and not under it like it would if I simply add a clear: right on Bravo.

Thanks

Comment: As per the edit: That seems to be exactly contradictory to what your original question stated.

Comment: The question now makes no sense!

Comment: I'm sorry, I think my question is clear and simple. How do I achieve the IE rendering (look at the screenshot) in the other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
Answer to the **new** question:

```css
<div id="A" style="float:right; background-color: Red; margin-top: -5px;">Alpha</div>
<div id="B" style="margin-top: 20px; background-color: Green;">Bravo</div>
```

**ORIGINAL**
*(The question author originally asked this and later changed the question...)*

Add `clear: right;` into B div's style. Optionally use `clear: both;`. And wrap div A into a wrapper div like this:

```css
<div id="wrapper" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="A" style="float:right; background-color: Red;">Alpha</div>
</div>
<div id="B" style="margin-top: 50px; background-color: Green; clear: right;">Bravo</div>
```

Comment: I thought of this but it creates an odd behavior where the green box is attached to the red box: http://jsfiddle.net/zP4H5/3/ - It appears to be ignoring the margin-top?

Comment: Try adding `margin-bottom: 50px;` to the A div and remove `margin-top: 50px;` from the B div. How is that?

Comment: Floating B and giving it width will give you the desired effect.

Comment: Here's info why the margin-top doesn't work with the float: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198269/in-css-margin-top-is-not-working-with-clear-both

Comment: Solution posted to the new question

Comment: @JarnoArgillander : Thanks, your edited answer seems to work. I'm sorry I changed the question. I probably should have started another question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="A" style="float:right; Background-color: Red;">Alpha</div>
    <div id="B" style="float:right; margin-top: 50px; Background-color: Green; clear:right; width:100%;">Bravo</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Added:

`float:right; clear:right;` and `width:100%;` to `#B`

See it in action - http://jsfiddle.net/SHubq/

Comment: I've edited my SS and question to specify that I really need Alpha to be floated on the right of Bravo. I'm sorry that I did not do so in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the [clear CSS rule](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp).

- add between your two `divs`

  `<div style="clear: both" />`. (Note : in your case, just `clear: right` works)

or

- add `clear: both` in the `div id="B"` style. (Note : in your case, just `clear: right` works)

Edit : See the two cases in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dyGyu/

Answer (score 0):

Add a `clear` property onto b's div style, use the property that is most appropriate to the site in question.

Such as `both` so you get nothing either side.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="A" style="float:right; Background-color: Red; ">Alpha</div>
    <div id="B" style="margin-top: 50px; Background-color: Green; clear: both;">Bravo</div>
  </body>
</html>
```