# Why the `clear:both` can not written into div.box3?

Tags: html, css

I want margin-top:10px to be displayed on the top of box3.
Here is the proper codes on firefox.
`<div class="clear"></div>` was written as a single line before div box3,and 
write `div.clear{clear:both;}` as a special part.

```css
    div.box{
        width:105px;
        height:200px;
        border:1px solid red;
        }
    div.box1{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        border:1px solid red;
        }
    div.box2{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        border:1px solid red;
        }
    div.clear{
        clear:both;
    }

    div.box3{
        width:100px;
        height:80px;
        border:1px solid red;
margin-top:10px;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="box">
    <div class="box1">box1</div>
     <div class="box2">box2</div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
     <div class="box3">box3</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now i move `clear:both;` in the div.box3,the whole css code as below.

```css
    div.box{
        width:105px;
        height:200px;
        border:1px solid red;
        }
    div.box1{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        border:1px solid red;
        }
    div.box2{
        float:left;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        border:1px solid red;
        }
    div.box3{
    clear:both;
        width:100px;
        height:80px;
        border:1px solid red;
        margin-top:10px;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="box">
    <div class="box1">box1</div>
     <div class="box2">box2</div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
     <div class="box3">box3</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

No 10px at the top of div.box3.
I  know right way to solve it ,want to know the  principle behind the proper css code.

Comment: Read up on [collapsing margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [margin-top not working with clear: both](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198269/margin-top-not-working-with-clear-both)