# HTML and CSS margin issues

Tags: html, css

[image]applying to my div #logo margin value forces all my other elements to follow this margin. It's in the "logo" div margin value. while setting it to 0 it's all comes up. i just want to move only this element slightly down. why? and how can i fix it?

```css
#logo  {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 200px; //!This!
}

#label {
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    
   
}

nav {
    
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

ul li{
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40px; 
    margin: 10px;
    border-bottom: 20px red;
    
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div id="label"><img src="3.png"></div>
        
       <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
           </nav>
        
        <div id="logo"><img src="1.png"></div>
        

    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#logo { position: relative; top: 200px; }
```

Relative positioning won't affect the position of the other elements.

Answer (score 1):

As said by @Uchit Kumar it's due to **margin collapsing** as you can read [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> Two margins are adjoining if and only if:
>
> ...
> ...
>
> both belong to vertically-adjacent box edges, i.e. form one of the following pairs:
>
> **top margin of a box and top margin of its first in-flow child**

And since all the child element are floated, the first in-flow child is `logo` so its margin will collapse with the one of the container (the body).

So the easiest fix would be to make the third element to float also:

```css
#logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  float:left
}

#label {
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-bottom: 20px red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="label"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/"></div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="logo"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/"></div>


</body>
```

But this solution is not the suitable one as it will change the behavior of the logo and maybe floating is not needed here.

Another fix to avoid margin collapsing is to add a small padding-top to container (the body):

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 padding-top:1px;/*added this */ 
}
#logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 300px;
  clear:both;
}

#label {
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-bottom: 20px red;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="label"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/"></div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="logo"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/"></div>


</body>
```

Or simply use margin-bottom in the previous element instead:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  clear: both;
}

#label {
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-bottom: 20px red;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="label"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/"></div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="logo"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/"></div>


</body>
```

---

Here is a very usefull link were you can find a more complete explanation about collapsing margin and floating:

[margin-top not working with clear: both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198269/margin-top-not-working-with-clear-both/41335816#41335816)

Answer (score 0):

quick fix is ..

```
#logo  {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    float: left
}
```

its may be due to margin collapsing... (not sure) 
read this.. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Comment: are you sure it's margin collpasing ? i don't think so, it's a simple float issue. You can add a small padding-top and the issue will remain so it cannot be margin collapsing

Comment: Adjacent siblings-- 
    The margins of adjacent siblings are collapsed (except when the latter sibling needs to be cleared past floats). 
so if you add clear both to #logo .. it will work properly

Comment: strange, i tried it but it's not working for me ... (and i think it's better to precise what kind of collpasing, cause i always go to the parent/child one :) )

Comment: one more strange thing... have you tried with code having this ... 

margin-top: 200px; //!This!  
try removing above  comment .. and adding clear  both

Comment: @TemaniAfif is it working now?

Comment: well the float:left is fixing the issue and not the clear:both .. clear:both alone doesn't fix the issue but float:left alone fix it

Comment: so am not really sure about the margin collpase .. i read also this *Note that the margins of floating and absolutely positioned elements never collapse.* Or maybe it collapse between float and non-float ? and not two float ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q2fdm6f7/ 
check this.

Comment: yes and you don't have margin in your code :) so there is an issue

Comment: and look here : https://jsfiddle.net/whkxjjzy/1/ we have margin, and it should be like this. So the clear both is not fixing the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162658/discussion-between-uchit-kumar-and-temani-afif).

Comment: added my answer :) took me time but i think it deserve it so we can understand it well ;)

Comment: and you may read this to understand about clear:both https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198269/margin-top-not-working-with-clear-both/41335816#41335816